# awk: match lines starting with any string except a pattern

Tags: regex, awk

I would like to extract all lines from a file which start with `%%` but not `%%%`. Imagine `foo.txt` to have such lines (and others). Then

```
awk '/^%%[^%]/ { printf "%s\n", $0 }' foo.txt
```

includes lines starting with `%%...`, it omits lines starting with `%%%...`, but it also omits lines **only** containing `%%` (which should be included). How can this be matched? I tried to explicitly match the 'rest' of the line with '.*', but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the end of line as well after the second percent.

Try:

```
awk '/^%%([^%]|$)/ { printf "%s\n", $0 }' foo.txt
```

Proof:

```
$ cat foo.txt
%% YES
%%% NO
%%
123
$ awk '/^%%([^%]|$)/ { printf "%s\n", $0 }' foo.txt
%% YES
%%
$
```

Comment: `'/^%%([^%]|$)/ { printf "%s\n", $0 }'` = just `/^%%([^%]|$)/` on it's own.

Comment: Indeed, that is much more idiomatic, and a very nice thing to add in case anyone lands here.